# Consulta em dbgrid paradox 7 usando edit em delphi

Tags: delphi-7

Sou muito interessado em aprender programação em Delphi. Já sei muitas coisas, mas ainda não sei manipulação de Database.
Bom, sem delongas. Queria saber como fazer consulta no database Paradox 7 com Delphi usando `TEdit` no exemplo abaixo:

No meu Form eu tenho um `TTable1`, `TDatasource1`, `TDbgrid1`, `TDbnavigator` e um `TEdit1`. Já está tudo devidamente ligado para retornar no `TDbgrid1` os valores da `TTable1`.

O que eu queria mesmo era digitar algo na caixa de texto e no grid apenas me mostrasse o que eu digitei ou o texto parcial no campo *usuario* do database.

Exemplo: Digitei na caixa de texto a palavra **a** e quero que ele mostre apenas palavras que começam com **a** sem distinção de maiúscula e minúscula no campo *usuario* do database. E também quando eu digitar parcialmente o texto ele me mostrasse as palavras que contenham aquele texto parcial no campo *usuario* do database.

Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar meu problema. Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

No caso o que você realmente quer fazer, exibir os dados na dbgrid?
No que entendi quer fazer uma query na tabela (table1), neste caso não é possível fazer, o que pode ser feito é um filtro. 
Você conhece os comandos básico do SQL (select, from, where )?
Então para o filtro os comandos que se destinam ao WHERE podem ser colocados no filtro, exemplo, se você tem um campo na tabela chamado CPF, pode colocar CPF='12345678912'.
Colocando no seu exemplo:
Table1: NOME, CPF (deve estar populada)
Então escreva no Table1.Filter a expressão CPF='12345678912' e mude o item Table1.Filtered para TRUE, execute o programa, o resultado é um filtro para na tabela para o item, se existir na tabela irá exibir.
Então se você colocar no Edit.Text esta expressão CPF='12345678912' e no click do botão, o seguinte comando:

```
table1.Filtered := false;
table1.Filter   := Edit1.text;
table1.Filtred  := True;
```

Terá o resultado que deseja.

Para começar isto já te ajuda?

Comment: obrigado, era o que eu precisava

Comment: Ok e bem vindo ao grupo.